# How can I list the group names that only the authenticated user belongs to while editing a user on the Django's admin panel?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to find out to restrict the group names for an admin user on Django. There are two groups in the system; "School One" and School "Two". The picture below shows the users belonging only to the "School Two" group (including me as John Doe).

[image]

For example, if I click the user "Josh Doe", I am directed to this page:
[image]

What I want is to display the groups that the current authenticated user (John Doe) belongs only. That way I can assign a group (or groups) to a particular user. So, here I want to see only "School Two" option as I (John Doe) belong only to that group (added by superuser).

How can I accomplish that?

Let me share my source codes with you:
admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm

class MyUserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_email_verified')

    def get_list_filter(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return ['groups']
        else:
            return ['is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_email_verified']

    readonly_fields = ('last_login', 'date_joined',)
    fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
    ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name','last_name')}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active','is_staff', 'groups')}),
    ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
)

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('first_name','last_name','email', 'password1', 'password2', 'groups')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        qs = qs.filter(groups__id__in=request.user.groups.all())
        return qs

admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

In the forms.py file:

```
class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        User = get_user_model()
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.is_staff = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

  password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

  class Meta:
     User = get_user_model()
     model = User
     fields = ('email', 'password', 'is_active','is_staff', 'groups')


  def clean_password(self):
          return self.initial["password"]
```

I would be glad if anybody could help with listing only the related group(s) as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to make that field read-only for non-superuser staff. I think the easiest way to do that is to use the [`get_readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields) method on the `ModelAdmin` class to make this field read-only based on who is editing. Something like this:

```
class MyUserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

    get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            fields = fields + ('groups',)
        return fields
```

Comment: If I try that, I am getting the "type object 'super' has no attribute 'get_readonly_fields'" error. Besides, that is not what I want. I don't want the groups just displayed as readonly field. I need to list those groups which belong only to the authorized user. In the example above, I should be able to see the only "School Two" and be able to edit it as well.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you want then. Making the field editable means by definition that you will be able to change which groups the user belongs to, which you say you don't want. What does it mean then to 'see only "School Two" and be able to edit it as well'? As for why the super method doesn't work, I had a typo in my answer which might be why it didn't work? There is definitely such a method in the parent class.

Comment: After fixing type, readonly works but I am writing an admin panel for schools. There are three types of users;superuser(me),staff (John Doe for example), regular user (no staff). A principle (staff - here John Doe) should be able to see only the group(s) he is a member of. In this case, he only belongs to School Two. He should be able to add users (this works) and make required changes. He should see only School Two in the groups.The application shows all the groups in the system. What if there would be hundreds of schools later. John Doe shouldn't see other schools that he is not a part of.